# Single click needed to run function instead of double click SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, flappy-bird-clone

Im making a flappy bird clone and when the bird dies, the spriteNode with restart button pop ups, but the fist click is stoping animation (if there any) and second click forse the restart() function

heres how i make SpriteNode menu with button:

```
 let menu = SKSpriteNode(texture: self.groundTex)
            menu.name = "menu"
            menu.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            menu.zPosition = 20
            let restartButton = SKSpriteNode(texture: self.heroTexture)
            restartButton.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
            restartButton.zPosition = 40
            restartButton.name = "restart"

            let moveMenu = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 2), duration: 1.0)

            self.menuNode.addChild(menu)
            menuNode.addChild(restartButton)
            self.addChild(menuNode)

            menu.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
                moveMenu,
                SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1.0)),
                makeGameEnd
                ]), withKey: "gameover"
```

here is how i detect touch:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch  = touches.first
    let location = touch?.locationInNode(self)
    let node: SKNode = nodeAtPoint(location!)



    if node.name == "restart" {
       restart()
    }
```

**UPDATE**
my restart():

```
func restart() {
let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Comment: Check if node.name is not nil then you are pressing button.

Comment: @Darvydas checked it, still 2 clicks needed. Actually it see thats its named "restart" but still needs 1 more click anywhere

Comment: that is node.name on the first click ?

Comment: @Darvydas yeap, in case i click on restart burron

Comment: Dima i think you do not understand what I'm saying. The problem might be that then you press your button you do not press node with name "restart". Try double checking what is the node.name when you press button. Good luck

Comment: @Darvydas node.name == "restart" on first click

Comment: @Darvydas updated post

Comment: let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0)
                    let nextScene = GameScene(size: scene!.size)
                    scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)

Comment: @Darvydas after changing it app freeze on the point of calling restart(), i have made a breakpoint at restart(), so the method called but the app is frozen

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a double tap like this

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch  = touches.first
    let location = touch?.locationInNode(self)
    let node: SKNode = nodeAtPoint(location!)

if touch.tapCount % 2 == 0 {

    if node.name == "restart" {
       restart()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i'm trying to get rid of double click on my button

Comment: So you need 1 tap? In your question you say 'Double click needed to run function instead of single click'

Comment: oh sorry, for bad explanation, yeah i need 1 tap instead of 2